# Is there any other logical or more robust way

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, select

I have a sql query

```
select count(salary)
from USER_DETAILS 
where salary>0 and salary<1000 union all
select count(salary)
from USER_DETAILS 
where salary>1000 and salary<10000 union all
select count(salary)
from USER_DETAILS 
where salary>10000 and salary<100000
```

Is there any other logical or more robust way of executing the same query(in hql preferably).

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be `case` statement would help

Comment: haven't used case till now don't know if it will work or not can you provide that query using "case" or any such link using "case".thanks btw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN salary >= 0 and salary <= 1000 THEN salary END) "salary >= 0 and salary <= 1000",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN salary >= 1000 and salary <= 10000 THEN salary END) "salary >= 1000 and salary <= 10000",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN salary >= 10000 and salary <= 100000 THEN salary END) "salary >= 10000 and salary <= 100000"
from    user_details
```

Comment: @CodeHunter - You should "accept" JW's answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try it using the CASE Statement

```
select  
     count(case when sal between 0 and 1000 then 1 end)
     count(case when sal between 1000 and 10000 then 1 end) ,
     count(case when sal between 10000 and 100000 then 1 end)
from user_details;
```

**Note**: You also have `else` keyword which can be placed at the end (if needed)

For example Refer
 1. [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=206)
 2. [This one goes with your requirement](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3344871/Oracles-CASE-Expression.htm)

Comment: are you aware that this will only return 1 record (*1 row with 1 column*)?

Comment: ya i thought so, but its giving some " not a single-group group function"